# Accessing elements of custom type variables in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a type called Animal which includes the animal's family and the color of the animal.

```
type Animal family = [(family, color)]

data Family = Ape | Bear | Bird | Cat | Dog | Chicken

data Color = Brown | Black | White | Other
```

I also have a function in which I am trying to access the family and color of an animal. All I am asking is simply *how* to access these elements from within a function. For example in most object oriented languages we would access these elements with something like *animal.family*.

```
animalFunction :: Animal -> String
animalFunction animal
    | animal.family == Ape = "This animal is an ape."
```

Comment: Did you mean `data Animal = Animal Family Color`? Currently `Animal a` is the type of a list of pairs.

Comment: If you want `animal.family` syntax, have a look at lenses (a little tutorial [here](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/a-little-lens-starter-tutorial) ). However lenses are an advanced topic in Haskell, and, as already mentioned, the record syntax is enough in your simple case.

Comment: @AntonGuryanov let's say *intermediate* :)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Not going crazy with them is advanced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
type Animal family = [(family, color)]
```

First and foremost, this shouldn't compile; would if changed to `[(family, Color)]`

This is a type alias, stating that `Animal` means *a list of tuples<sup>1</sup> of (parametrized family type, color)*, which is most probably not what you want.

As @rightfold suggested, you probably wanted

```
data Animal = Animal Family Color
```

Or, using record syntax:

```
data Animal = Animal { family :: Family, color :: Color }
```

Then, your function:

```
-- record version
animalFunction :: Animal -> String
animalFunction animal
    | family animal == Ape = "This animal is an ape."
    | ...
```

> Note: `family :: Animal -> Family`

Or you can just pattern match<sup>2</sup>.

```
animalFunction (Animal f c)
    | f == Ape = ...
```

or even:

```
animalFunction (Animal Ape _) = ...
```

---

However, what you're probably looking for is `Show`, as a general, idiomatic way to convert something to `String`<sup>3</sup>.

```
data Family = Ape | Bear | Bird | Cat | Dog | Chicken deriving (Show)

instance Show Animal where
    show (Animal f _) = "This animal is an " ++ (show f) ++ "."
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Pairs.

<sup>2</sup> It works with both records and non-records, because records only really introduce getters of type `Record -> Member` for every member, and they don't modify the structure

<sup>3</sup> In other languages, you can think about this as implementing "ToString" interface for your class. It's an oversimplification, but enough to understand this example.

Comment: I'd tend to prefer the pattern `Animal{family = Ape}`, FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

To test for cases of an algebraic data type you should use pattern matching instead of if statements or guards:

```
case myFamily of
  Ape -> "This is an ape"
  Bear -> "Dangerous carnivore!"
  Bird -> "This can fly"
  -- and so on...
```